# How to make a C++ function execute with a double parameter or no parameter

Tags: c++

I have a bit of code and I have 3 overloaded functions. I want one of them to accept a double as a parameter or to be called if there are no passed arguments. The others accept only an int and the other a char, that's it. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Yes. dasblinkenlight answered my question below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a function to execute when users make a call with no parameters, give your parameter a default:

```
void foo(double d = 0.0) {
    ...
}
void foo(int i) {
    ...
}
void foo(char c) {
    ...
}
```

When users call `foo()`, the overload taking `double` will be called. The code would be executed as if zero has been passed.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(double x=0.0) // give it a default value for it to be called with no arguments
{
    cout<<"foo(double) is being called"<<endl;
}

void foo(int x)
{
    cout<<"foo(int) is being called"<<endl;
}

void foo(char x)
{
    cout<<"foo(char) is being called"<<endl;
}

int main() 
{
    foo();
    foo(3.5);
    foo(10);
    foo('c');

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
foo(double) is being called
foo(double) is being called
foo(int) is being called
foo(char) is being called